# Do I have to transfer landside, and do I have enough time? (British, LGW-KEF-UAK)

Tags: air-travel, transit, kef

In a few weeks I will be travelling to Greenland for a hiking and kayaking trip. I will have checked baggage. The flight from Iceland to Greenland is included, and is with Air Iceland. I have booked separately with WOW to get me to Iceland.

WOW does not interline baggage.
Air Iceland does not have online check-in when flying from Keflavik.

Am I right in thinking that I have to collect my bag, enter Iceland, then check in and go through security in the main building again as if it was my first flight? Is 3h25 plenty of time to do this and eat?

Comment: You will pass immigration control before collecting your bag, not after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's about right. 3 hours sounds eminently doable; it's not a large airport and most passengers transit anyway, so there are not huge security lines.

Of course, if your incoming flight from London is delayed and you don't make it, you'll be on your own, with your onwards ticket lost as a no-show.  Flights to Narsarsuaq are only twice a week, and possibly expensive on short notice -- or may even be sold out, as the August 12 and 15 departures currently are -- so if it were me, I think I would plan to arrive in Iceland the day before, just in case.

Comment: 15th is the one I'm on. Yes I'll be hosed if there's that bad a delay. There's an Icelandair flight a bit later as an alternative to the WOW one, but that could itself get full or at least be eye-wateringly expensive.

Comment: https://sv.flightaware.com/live/flight/WOW815

Comment: @DaveFF It looks like the average delay is 10-20 minutes. If we approximate delays to be distributed Poisson, we'd get a variance of 20 minutes as well, or a standard deviation of 4 minutes: There'd be a 1% chance of a delay of less than 10 minutes, and a 1% chance of a delay of more than 30 minutes.

Comment: @FooBar: I doubt that is a valid model for estimating the prevalence of _long_ delays. An entire different set of causes start being relevant, which simply doesn't affect observations of _short_ delays. (There is no such thing as "needed a new aircraft to be sent from Iceland, but only slightly so, resulting in a 20-minute delay").